# How to correct a goto:eof and multi counter in batch

Tags: batch-file

Cleaning up my question
Will update it with smaller scripts

Comment: I don't understand your problem. `Goto :eof` is the usual way to return from al `call`ed subroutine.

Comment: @Stephan - Yes sorry, I didn't want to over flood the question, but the script will edit a code or multiple codes in my files, and their is nothing wrong with the `eof` but I have been trying to add a second `goto` where it will take me back to my main menu, `choice /c 123456789 /n /m "Make Your Choice"` but what happens is that the CMD closes when it's done, I'm trying to make it not close and but instead return goto: Workstation

Comment: Don't you want to change the other `goto :eof` (the one after the `for` loop) instead?

Comment: yes. `:eof` is just an internal, predefined label, meaning **e**nd **o**f **f**ile. Of course, you can jump somewhere else.

Comment: still trying to reconstruct your environment based on your code. You could help by creating a minimal reproducible program (one that we can copy/paste and execute without being dependent on things we can only guess)

Comment: @Stephan - OK, I have updated the question and results hopefully this helps, now this might now work, because this was a tester I was working on and I was able to make the counter count from 1 to 18, but that's it, with the before you can copy and paste it as many times as you like in the same file to make it as long as you want

Comment: uhm - are you sure you need to *edit* the file? Rewriting it from scratch would be much easier (23 lines)

Comment: OK, I found `gtr` will fix the counts not `neg` now need to find how to stop it at 6